# Google cloud streaming dataflow : Error while fetching side input

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Sometimes I am getting below exception while running streaming dataflow :

```
  exception:  "java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while fetching side input: 
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StateFetcher.fetchSideInput(StateFetcher.java:184)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext.fetchSideInput(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:175)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext.access$400(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:56)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext$StepContext.issueSideInputFetch(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:401)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingSideInputFetcher.getReadyWindows(StreamingSideInputFetcher.java:135)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.startBundle(StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.java:49)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.reallyStartBundle(SimpleParDoFn.java:175)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.startBundle(SimpleParDoFn.java:117)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.startBundle(ForwardingParDoFn.java:36)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.start(ParDoOperation.java:45)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:69)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:719)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$600(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:95)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:538)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate values for 2059
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2207)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3953)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4790)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StateFetcher.fetchSideInput(StateFetcher.java:175)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate values for 2059
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PCollectionViews$MapPCollectionView.fromElements(PCollectionViews.java:291)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PCollectionViews$MapPCollectionView.fromElements(PCollectionViews.java:273)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.PCollectionViews$PCollectionViewBase.fromIterableInternal(PCollectionViews.java:368)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StateFetcher$2.call(StateFetcher.java:152)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StateFetcher$2.call(StateFetcher.java:104)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4793)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3542)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2323)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2286)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2201)
... 19 more
```

Dataflow worker machine type : n1-standard-4

Worker cache memory Mb : 2048

Dataflow main Input : PubSub subscription.
I am creating sideInput from BT , and passing this sideInputs to multiple transformations.The size of my sideinput is less that 100Mb.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that multiple values with the same key (2059) have been encountered, which violates the expectations for a Map-valued side input. This can happen in streaming especially if you trigger the same value multiple times. If you instead use a Multimap, it should allow you to retrieve all of the values associated with a given key.