# How to solve PCollection with more than one element accessed as a singleton view

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The pipeline of beam job give the following exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while fetching side input: 
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:184)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.emit(ReduceFnRunner.java:930)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:790)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:95)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1316)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:149)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1049)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while fetching side input: 
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StateFetcher.fetchSideInput(StateFetcher.java:196)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext.fetchSideInput(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:313)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext.access$500(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:70)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext$StepContext.issueSideInputFetch(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:660)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext$UserStepContext.issueSideInputFetch(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:723)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputFetcher.storeIfBlocked(StreamingSideInputFetcher.java:184)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.processElement(StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.java:72)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:182)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.emit(ReduceFnRunner.java:930)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:790)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:95)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1316)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:149)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1049)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PCollection with more than one element accessed as a singleton view.
        org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2050)
        org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4871)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StateFetcher.fetchSideInput(StateFetcher.java:192)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext.fetchSideInput(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:313)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext.access$500(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:70)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext$StepContext.issueSideInputFetch(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:660)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext$UserStepContext.issueSideInputFetch(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:723)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputFetcher.storeIfBlocked(StreamingSideInputFetcher.java:184)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.processElement(StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.java:72)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:182)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.emit(ReduceFnRunner.java:930)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:790)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:95)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1316)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:149)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1049)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PCollection with more than one element accessed as a singleton view.
        org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionViews$SingletonViewFn.apply(PCollectionViews.java:231)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollectionViews$SingletonViewFn.apply(PCollectionViews.java:160)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StateFetcher.lambda$fetchSideInput$1(StateFetcher.java:162)
        org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4876)
        org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528)
        org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277)
        org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154)
        org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044)
        org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952)
        org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4871)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StateFetcher.fetchSideInput(StateFetcher.java:192)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext.fetchSideInput(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:313)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext.access$500(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:70)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext$StepContext.issueSideInputFetch(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:660)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext$UserStepContext.issueSideInputFetch(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:723)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputFetcher.storeIfBlocked(StreamingSideInputFetcher.java:184)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.processElement(StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.java:72)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:335)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:182)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.emit(ReduceFnRunner.java:930)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:790)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:95)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1316)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:149)
        org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1049)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

With codes snippets. And the beam job is read data from GCS through subscription and write bigquery after processing.

```java
PCollection<KV<String, Long>> p1 = interToCount.apply("Daily Window",
        Window.<KV<String, Long>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardDays(1)))
                .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                                                                  .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(10))))
                .accumulatingFiredPanes()
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO));

PCollectionView<Long> totalInters = p1.apply("All Keys", Keys.create())
                                      .apply("Count All Keys", 
                                            Combine.globally(Count.<String>combineFn())
                                                                  .withoutDefaults()
                                                                  .asSingletonView());

PCollection<KV<String, Long>> p2 = p1.apply("Unit Keys", Keys.create())
                                      .apply("Count Per Unit Keys", Count.perElement());

PCollection<KV<String, Double>> unitRate = p2.apply("Compute Unit Rate",
                                                    ParDo.of(new ComputeUnitRate(totalInters))
                                                         .withSideInputs(totalInters));

unitRate.apply("Convert to BQ Row", ParDo.of(new ConvertStrToBQRow()))
        .apply("Write BQ", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to(INTERSHOWTABLE)
                                    .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
                                    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                                    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND));
....

    static class ComputeUnitRate extends DoFn<KV<String, Long>, KV<String, Double>> {
        private PCollectionView<Long> totalInters;

        ComputeUnitRate(PCollectionView<Long> totalInters) {
            this.totalInters = totalInters;
        }

        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            String unit = c.element().getKey();
            Long unitCount = c.element().getValue();
            Long totalCount = c.sideInput(this.totalInters);
            Double showRate = unitCount.doubleValue() / totalCount.doubleValue();
            c.output(KV.of(unit, showRate));
        }
    }
```

It seems this error comes from step "Compute Unit Rate", However I cannot figure out clearly through exception stack.

How to fix it? Or something am I missing here?

Beam version: 2.16.0

Comment: where is that error occuring, on what line? what does `ComputeUnitRate` do?

Comment: @TravisWebb, I have updated my question. Hope it will be more clearly now

Comment: @TravisWebb, It seems same error come up in this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542126/google-cloud-streaming-dataflow-error-while-fetching-side-input, However, I cannot find correct solution here

Answer (score 1):

Per this [doc](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@beam.apache.org/msg02129.html)

> This is a known issue in the Beam model. Trigger firings should
> automatically update downstream results, but instead they are treated as
> new elements. The design for retractions will alleviate this problem
>
> You can use View.asMultimap() which will mean each trigger firing for a
> key will add a new element to the set of values for a key.

After change `PCollectionView` to `PCollectionView<Map<Long, Long>>` as below

```java
PCollectionView<Map<Long, Long>> totalInters = p1.apply("All Keys", Keys.create())
        .apply("Count All Keys", Combine.globally(Count.<String>combineFn()).withoutDefaults())
        .apply("Map view multiMap", ParDo.of(new DoFn<Long, KV<Long, Long>>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void process(ProcessContext ctx) {
                ctx.output(KV.of(ctx.pane().getIndex(), ctx.element().longValue()));
            }
        }))
        .apply(View.asMap())
        ;
```

The pipeline could work well now.

I think maybe it is one of work around for this issue for now. Maybe there are better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and I set higher numWorkers and maxNumWorkers, it resolved the problem.
you can do either `options.setNumWorkers(DEFAULT_NB_WORKER);` in code
or use mvn to start DataflowRunner with --numWorkers=xx --maxNumWorkers=xx